# Is an active Paid Applications Contract required for testing In App Purchase?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I was following a [tutorial on In App Purchase](http://www.raywenderlich.com/21081/introduction-to-in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial) which also shows how to test by using the [sandbox environment](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/DevelopingwithStoreKit/DevelopingwithStoreKit.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH103-SW1). As I've tried to add an In App Purchase to my Application the iTunes Connect prompted following hint:

*You do not have a contract in place for the price tier you selected. To make your app available on the App Store, you must have an active Paid Applications Contract.*

Am I still able to test In App Purchase?

Comment: http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=584149

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For adding and testing InApp purchase in your application you have to agreed on apple contract for paid application and provide your contact info , bank info, and tax info. You have to login in itunesconnect.apple.com and click on contract, tax and banking.

After providing above info you can see Manage In App Purchase Button on itunes connect web site and you can add your product.

Comment: Thanks, do you know how long it takes until I can start adding purchases?

Comment: It won't take more than a week in general.

Comment: For me the "Manage In App Purchase" button is visible although I did not provide any bank info yet. I'm also able to add and configure products in iTunes Connect. However, all product request I perform in my app return no results. Do I really need to add my bank info before I can test IAPs in my app? This would be ridiculous...

Comment: wow. I've been stuck on this for longer than I care to admit. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: Same here, they didn't approve it yet, but I read everywhere, that it needs to be processed to be able to fetch your products, until that the request will return only invalid product ids.

Comment: @FrankSchlegel so did you solve it? Did you have to add all info before testing?

Comment: @user924 To be honest I can't remember. This was over 4 years ago . But I think I just provided the required info.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a Paid Applications contract in the Contracts, Tax, & Banking Information section of iTunes Connect. You will need a bunch of info about your bank, and it will take many days, possibly weeks, for them to hand process the request.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. if don't do it, Product count will always return "0" in your code.

You have to fill Series of question for "Tax form"(Non-Us resident).
Then 'Set up Contact' Even if you are Individually making apps i.e Not a company.

Fill your own contact details in every field.

Paid App Status turned "Active" Within Half hour.