# ios in app purchase testing - agreements, tax, banking setup required?

Tags: ios, in-app

i am new to iOS and am building an app that has in-app purchase. The app is not yet ready(not in app store) and i am trying to test in-app purchase. I have created the products in iTunes Connect as per the documentation, however, everytime i try to get the list of products from my app, it's always showing up in invalid product identifiers.

I did not setup agreements, tax and banking yet and am not sure if this is required even to test in-app purchase?

THanks

Comment: did you get any info on this? i'm having the same issue. my tax setup is not finished and getting invalid product ids.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is an active Paid Applications Contract required for testing In App Purchase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14957328/is-an-active-paid-applications-contract-required-for-testing-in-app-purchase)