# Is agreements, tax, banking setup required in order to test In-app purchase?

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase

This question has been asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32687438/ios-in-app-purchase-testing-agreements-tax-banking-setup-required) however no one has given the user an answer. I am in the same situation and I was wondering if someone has the answer to it?

Here is the question again:

"I am new to iOS and am building an app that has in-app purchase. The app is not yet ready(not in app store) and i am trying to test in-app purchase. I have created the products in iTunes Connect as per the documentation, however, everytime i try to get the list of products from my app, it's always showing up in invalid product identifiers.

I did not setup agreements, tax and banking yet and am not sure if this is required even to test in-app purchase?"

What could be the reason to be getting invalid product IDs even though I have triple checked that Im using the correct product ids when making SKProductsRequest, and all the itune setup is done with products in "ready to submit" state. Im literally going crazy and dont know what to do :(

Thank you

Comment: yes it is required .

Answer (score 1):

> In-App Purchase allows you to sell additional features and
>   functionality from within your iOS, macOS, and tvOS apps. If you wish
>   to offer in-app purchases in your applications, you must complete
>   several steps before you can do it. This document provides
>   step-by-step instructions for setting up and testing in-app purchase.
>   It also answers common questions about in-app purchase. The
>   "Agreements, Tax, and Banking Information" section describes all the
>   financial documents that must be completed.
>   [Explanation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2259/_index.html)

Comment: Welcome mate @beckas

Comment: Im still not sure, but it helped reading it...im waiting for agreements, tax and banking setup to be sure